# How to resolve ambiguous selector in Go

Tags: go, struct, interface

I define two struct types Type1 and Type2

```
type Type1 struct {
A1,B1,C1 string
}
type Type2 struct {
A1,B1 string
}
```

to embed them in struct type Supertype

```
type Supertype struct {
    Type1
    Type2
}
```

then define interface Sender with method Send in order to use for both Type1 and Type2

```
type Sender interface {
    Send() 
}
```

Finally I define func where I want to refer Type1 and Type2 fields

```
func (p Supertype) Send() {
..
p.A1 = "foo"
..

}
```

of course getting **'ambiguous selector p.A1'** error. How to use method Send for both struct types Type1 and Type2 ? There is similar question *How can two different types implement the same method in golang using interfaces?* but I don't think it applies in my case

Answer (score 23):

You can use

```
p.Type1.A1
```

if `Type2` too has the same field `A1`